# Lock Relative Referencing in Excel with R1C1

Tags: excel

Is there a way of locking down the relative reference in a R1C1 style forumla. For example adding a row the just before the reference changes the formula from RC[-1] to RC[-2] however I want it to remain static i.e. RC[-1].

Answer (score 4):

*Absolute* referencing in `R1C1` just uses the row and column numbers. 
*Relative* referencing uses square brackets `[]`. 
Examples:

```
+-------------------------+------------+
| $B$3 == row 3 column 2  | R3C2       |
| This row this column    | RC         |
| This row column 2       | RC2        |
| this row 2 columns left | RC[-2]     |
| row 3 2 columns left    | R3C[-2]    |
| Row above 1 column left | R[-1]C[-1] |
+-------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Charles thanks for the reply. That isn't really what I mean. I want RC[-1] to be the same formula even if insert a row between the formula and data set.

Comment: 2 Solutions - none of them ideal. 1. use =OFFSET(RC,0,-1) 2. use  =INDIRECT("C3")  Both of these use Volatile functions