# Explain in laymans terms what these Excel R1C1 formulas are doing so I may learn how to edit them?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019, excel-r1c1-notation

Windows 10
Excel 2019

Can anyone explain in lay terms what the R1C1 formulas are doing, preferably in standard Excel terms (non R1C1)

I have a workbook with two worksheets and the below VBA code pulls selected data from one worksheet "Track Data2" into the second.
It is pulling from 7 columns but I now need to add a further 3.

Rather than ask for the code I want to learn what the below code is doing so I can do it myself.

```
'   Starting with cell A2 through to cell H2, and down to row 40,000, this inserts the forumlas to
'   pull the data from the worksheet "Track Data2

'   As the formulas are in R1C1 format, and not the standard excel format, I have no idea what the
'   formulas are actually doing so I am unable to change them or add extra columns.
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC)"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC)"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC[2])"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC[2])"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC[2])"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-6]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC[2])
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-7]="""","""",'Track Data'!RC[2])"


'   I know that this auto fills the formulas down the columns
Range("A2:H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:H40000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:H40000").Select
Application.GoTo Reference:="R2C1"
```

I have searched on google, and Microsoft.com but there is nothing that is able to explaing what the formulas are doing or how i may edit them or add extra columns if I wish to do so.

Comment: Google "R1C1 Brackets" and you'll find plenty of explanations.

Comment: Although the question is not the exact same, the answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802581/lock-relative-referencing-in-excel-with-r1c1) illustrates things pretty well.

Comment: In a nutshell: RxCy just means row x column y. Without the x or the y it means current row/column, such as RC1 meaning current row first column. With [ ] brackets it's relative to current row/column, so R[-1]C[3] would mean one row above and three columns to the right. You can mix those modes, e.g. R[1]C2 means next row second column. And with sheet name and exclamation mark in front, it refers to another sheet, but that's the same as it is in A1 notation too.

Comment: Btw in your code it doesn't even make sense to use relative column references at the start of the `IF`, since they all refer to the first column of the current row effectively, they could all just be `RC1`.

Comment: No need for the `Select` step - just use (eg) `Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = ...`

Comment: They closed this question by saying it was a duplicate of a question that has an answer that doesn't answer the question.  This one might be a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977365/how-to-i-make-an-absolute-reference-using-r1c1-format-in-vba-for-excel